# resize image two or three time via javascript

Tags: javascript, image, resize

could we do this with javascript?

consider we have a    x * y px    div
(width=x and hight=y)

and user uploads image in any size, I want to find a way this image not to be Deformed in Container.
I have a senario but not sure it's possible via javascript or jquery in addition of css. you can see my senario below but I dont know how can I write correctly in javascript

```
var ContainerWidth=document.getElementById("Container").width;
var ContainerHight=document.getElementById("Container").height;
var imgWidth = document.getElementById("myImg").width;
var imgHight =document.getElementById("myImg").height;


 if   imgWidth  > ContainerWidth
{
 myimg.style.width = ContainerWidth;
var newHightOfmyimg= myimg.style.height = 'auto';???????????????????????? the main     problem: how can I know what is this auto height in px and how can set it in a var?
}

if newHightOfmyimg > ContainerHight
{
UltimateimgHight= ContainerHight;

UltimateimgWidth=auto;
}
```

Comment: I assume your container to be quadratic. Then check if width or height is larger. If e.g. the width is larger, set the images width to the container width and calculate the resizefactor between the 2 widths. Use this factor to calculate the height and center the image in your container afterwards.

Comment: Do you HAVE to use JavaScript? You can do this with CSS. E.G: http://jsfiddle.net/8LNUQ/

Answer (score 0):

firstly to get the style of a property using javascript, you should do the following

```
var containerWidth = document.getElementById('Container').style.width;
var containerHeight = document.getElementById('Conatiner').style.height;
var imgWidth = document.getElementById('myImg').style.width;
var imgHeight= document.getElementById('myImg').style.height;
```

that will return the style set by the CSS itself.

secondly, auto is the original width / height of the element. if you want your image or any element to get it's parent's width / height then you could use inherit in CSS.